# To express then in terms of characteristics function. A linear transformation to Fun(S).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

> Let $S=\{-1,0,1\}$ and $T\colon\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)\to\operatorname{Fun}(S)$ be the transformation $T(p(x))=p'(x)$
>
> and consider the ordered bases
> \begin{align}
> E &= \{1,x,x^2\}\ \text{the standard basis of $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)$,} \\
> F &= \{1-x,x+x^2,2+x^2\}\ \text{a basis of source $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)$,} \\
> E' &= \{\chi_{-1},\chi_0,\chi_1\}\ \text{the standard basis of $\operatorname{Fun}(S)$,} \\
> G &= \{\chi_{-1},\chi_1-2\chi{-1},\chi_{-1}+\chi_0-2\chi_1\}\ \text{a basis of target $\operatorname{Fun}(S)$.}
> \end{align}

I have to find the matrices of the transformation T. But I am not understating the  following:
$T(1) = 0, T(x) = 1$ and $T(x^2) = 2x$ but how to express then in terms of characteristics function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $\operatorname{Fun}(S)$ denotes the set of functions $S\to\mathbb R$.

Now what does the map $T$ do? It takes a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)$ and sends it to the map $S\to\mathbb R$ given by $s\mapsto p'(s)$. So we get
\begin{align}
T(1) = (s\mapsto 0) &= 0\cdot\chi_{-1}{}+0\cdot \chi_0 + 0\cdot \chi_1,\\
T(x) = (s\mapsto 1) &= 1\cdot\chi_{-1}{}+1\cdot \chi_0 + 1\cdot \chi_1,\\
T(x^2) = (s\mapsto 2s) &= \left(s\mapsto \begin{cases}
-2 & \text{if $s=-1$} \\
0 & \text{if $s=0$} \\
2 & \text{if $s=1$} 
\end{cases}\right)\\
 &=(-2)\cdot\chi_{-1}{}+0\cdot \chi_0 + 2\cdot \chi_1.
\end{align}

Note that in general a function $f\colon S\to\mathbb R$ can always be written as
$$
f = f(-1)\cdot\chi_{-1} + f(0)\cdot\chi_0 + f(1)\cdot\chi_1.
$$